# Creating OOBB from points

Tags: c++, graphics, geometry, 3d, 3d-reconstruction

How can I create minimal OOBB for given points? Creating AABB or sphere is very easy, but I have problems creating minimal OOBB.

[edit]

First answer didn't get me good results. I don't have huge cloud of points. I have little amount of points. I am doing collision geometry generation. For example, cube has 36 points (6 sides, 2 triangles each, 3 points for each triangle). And algorithm from first post gave bad results for cube. Example points for cube: http://nopaste.dk/download/3382 (should return identity axis)

Comment: From the top of my head I would do something like compute the convex hull, compute the variance matrix of the exterior points (points in the convex hull), then construct the OOBB from the eigenvectors of said covariance matrix. This is not optimal but should produce decent results. For an optimal algorithm see e.g. http://www.springerlink.com/index/L28G0XK0P631U051.pdf (not free unfortunately)

Comment: I took a class on this in college, and I faintly remember having to start out by finding the two most distant points, and using the line between them as one of your axes for the OBB, then from there you somehow construct the other two axes.  A horribly incomplete answer, I know, but thats why I made it a comment

Comment: The OOBB problem in 3D is hard, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms). The O'Rourke's paper mentioned there can be found [here](http://maven.smith.edu/~orourke/Papers/MinVolBox.pdf).

Comment: If you have time look at: http://gabyx.github.io/ApproxMVBB/

Comment: may be porting this [How to Compute OBB of Multiple Curves?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42997918/2521214) to 3D and use recursive increase in accuracy would help

Answer (score 19):

The PCA/covariance/eigenvector method essentially finds the axes of an ellipsoid that approximates the vertices of your object. It should work for random objects, but will give bad results for symmetric objects like the cube. That's because the approximating ellipsoid for a cube is a sphere, and a sphere does not have well defined axes.  So you're not getting the standard axes that you expect.

Perhaps if you know in advance that an object is, for example, a cube you can use a specialized method, and use PCA for everything else.

On the other hand, if you want to compute the true OBB there are existing implementations you can use e.g. http://www.geometrictools.com/LibMathematics/Containment/Containment.html
(archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20110817024344/geometrictools.com/LibMathematics/Containment/Containment.html and https://github.com/timprepscius/GeometricTools/blob/master/WildMagic5/LibMathematics/Containment/Wm5ContMinBox3.cpp).  I believe this implements the algorithm alluded to in the comments to your question.

Quoting from that page:

> The ContMinBox3 files implement an
>   algorithm for computing the
>   minimum-volume box containing the
>   points. This method computes the
>   convex hull of the points, a convex
>   polyhedron. The minimum-volume box
>   either has a face coincident with a
>   face of the convex polyhedron or has
>   axis directions given by three
>   mutually perpendicular edges of the
>   convex polyhedron. Each face of the
>   convex polyhedron is processed by
>   projecting the polyhedron to the plane
>   of the face, computing the
>   minimum-area rectangle containing the
>   projections, and computing the
>   minimum-length interval containing the
>   projections onto the perpendicular of
>   the face. The minimum-area rectangle
>   and minimum-length interval combine to
>   form a candidate box. Then all triples
>   of edges of the convex polyhedron are
>   processed. If any triple has mutually
>   perpendicular edges, the smallest box
>   with axes in the directions of the
>   edges is computed. Of all these boxes,
>   the one with the smallest volume is
>   the minimum-volume box containing the
>   original point set.

If, as you say, your objects do not have a large number of vertices, the running time should be acceptable.

In a discussion at http://www.gamedev.net/topic/320675-how-to-create-oriented-bounding-box/ the author of the above library casts some more light on the topic:

> Gottschalk's approach to OBB construction is to compute a covariance matrix for the point set. The eigenvectors of this matrix are the OBB axes. The average of the points is the OBB center. The OBB is not guaranteed to have the minimum volume of all containing boxes. An OBB tree is built by recursively splitting the triangle mesh whose vertices are the point set. A couple of heuristics are mentioned for the splitting.
>
> The minimum volume box (MVB) containing a point set is the minimum volume box containing the convex hull of the points. The hull is a convex polyhedron. Based on a result of Joe O'Rourke, the MVB is supported by a face of the polyhedron or by three perpendicular edges of the polyhedron. "Supported by a face" means that the MVB has a face coincident with a polyhedron face. "Supported by three perpendicular edges" means that three perpendicular edges of the MVB are coincident with edges of the polyhedron.
>
> As jyk indicates, the implementations of any of these algorithms is not trivial. However, never let that discourage you from trying :) An AABB can be a good fit, but it can also be a very bad fit. Consider a "thin" cylinder with end points at (0,0,0) and (1,1,1) [imagine the cylinder is the line segment connecting the points]. The AABB is 0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1, and 0 <= z <= 1, with a volume of 1. The MVB has center (1,1,1)/2, an axis (1,1,1)/sqrt(3), and an extent for this axis of sqrt(3)/2. It also has two additional axes perpendicular to the first axis, but the extents are 0. The volume of this box is 0. If you give the line segment a little thickness, the MVB becomes slightly larger, but still has a volume much smaller than that of the AABB.
>
> Which type of box you choose should depend on your own application's data.
>
> Implementations of all of this are at my www.geometrictools.com website. I use the median-split heuristic for the bounding-volume trees. The MVB construction requires a convex hull finder in 2D, a convex hull finder in 3D, and a method for computing the minimum area box containing a set of planar points--I use the rotating caliper method for this.

Answer (score 10):

First you have to compute the centroid of the points, in pseudcode

```
mu = sum(0..N, x[i]) / N
```

then you have to compute the covariance matrix

```
C = sum(0..N, mult(x[i]-mu, transpose(x[i]-mu)));
```

Note that the mult performs an (3x1) matrix multiplication by (1x3) matrix multiplication, and the result is a 3x3 matrix.

The eigenvectors of the C matrix define the three axis of the OBB.

Comment: Note that this is an approximate method.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, but it should be sufficient for most applications, considering its easy computation.

Comment: @Mark - This answer is a good one.  This solution is very close to Principle Component Analysis (PCA). In the most strict sense, it is an "approximation" as n.m. states.  However, don't let that label dissuade you from using it. This method will accurately describe the 3D point set within bounds defined by the statistical properties of the data (i.e. number of points, denseness of sampling, distribution of sampling, etc.)

Comment: @Throw @Christian This method gave me bad results for very simple case. I've edited my answer, please take a look.

Comment: @Mark so would you say implementing davidnr would be a fair assumption to give good results? i been tracking an obb computation online so i can understand it better and this is the first one that seems to give some better understanding.

Answer (score 6):

There is a new library **`ApproxMVBB`** in C++ online which computes an **approximation for the minimum volume bounding box**. Its released under MPL 2.0 Licences, and written by me.

If you have time look at: http://gabyx.github.io/ApproxMVBB/

The library is C++11 compatible and only needs Eigen http://eigen.tuxfamily.org.
Tests show that an approximation for 140Million points in 3D can be computed in reasonable time (arround 5-7 seconds) depending on your settings for the approximation.

Comment: its a bad library, very hard to integrate

Comment: where are your problems? I might give you a hand. It should be easy to build on linux and  to use the `find_package(ApproxMVBB,...` to use it in your project. If it is hard to integrate with other libraries, consider adding a issue at github.

Comment: i tried this a while back. was hoping to integrate with PCL but I was not able to get it to work. I might look back at it again if I am free

Comment: it should be possible to integrate or at least to use a point cloud from PCL and interfacing ApproxMVBB, I have worked with that in the past, I will see if I can make an example in the library

Comment: Gabriel,  Do u have samples that works with PCL library?

Comment: Unfortunately not, since I have not worked a lot latetely on these. There is a fork I think: https://github.com/tyronedong/ApproxMVBB-backup/blob/master/example/approxMVBB/src/main.cpp
Look here.