# How to Compute OBB of Multiple Curves?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, computational-geometry

Given a number of curves，include line segments and circular arcs, how to compute the total OBB of all curves?

It seems that the union of each OBB of the individual curves does not right, it's not the minimal coverage.

Check this picture, how to compute the red box?

[image: img]

Comment: Why do you use OBB for line segments. Isn't the OBB of a line segment the segment itself?

Comment: Yes, that indeed for a single line segment, but this algorithm is used to compute OBB of multiple curves? If there are 2 non-collinear line segments, the OBB would not be a line segment.

Comment: @My_Cat_Jessica added image with real data ...and C++ source I used to create the image I busted as proof of concept

Comment: Sample points along those curves to obtain a point set, then use the algorithm described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189229/creating-oobb-from-points

Comment: thanks, that's a deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should also add the input in vector form so we can test on your data ... I would approach like this:

1. **find center of axis aligned bbox `O(n)`**
2. **compute max distance in each angle `O(n)`**

   just create table for enough `m` angles (like 5 deg step so `m = 360/5`) where for each angle section you remember max distant point distance only.
3. **compute max perpendicular distance for each rotation `O(m^2)`**

   so for each angle section compute value that is:

   ```
   value[actual_section] = max(distance[i]*cos(section_angle[i]-section_angle[actual_section]))
   ```

   where `i` covers `+/- 90 deg` around actual section angle so now you got max perpendicular distances for each angle...
4. **pick best solution `O(m)`**

   so look all rotations from 0 to 90 degrees and remember the one that has minimal **OBB** area. Just to be sure the **OBB** is aligned to section angle and size of axises is the `value` of that angle and all the 90 deg increments... around center

   [image: sketch]

This will not result in optimal solution but very close to it. To improve precision you can use more angle sections or even recursively search around found solution with smaller and smaller angle step (no need to compute the other angle areas after first run.

**[Edit1]**

I tried to code this in **C++** as proof of concept and use your image (handled as set of points) as input so here the result so you got something to compare to (for debugging purposes)

[image: example]

**gray** are detected points from your image, **green** rectangle is axis aligned **BBox** the **red** rectangle is found **OBBox**. The **aqua** points are found max distance per angle interval and **green** dots are max perpendicular distance for `+/-90deg` neighbor angle intervals. I used `400` angles and as you can see the result is pretty close ... `360/400 deg` accuracy so this approach works well ...

**Here C++ source:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct _pnt2D
    {
    double x,y;
    // inline
    _pnt2D()    {}
    _pnt2D(_pnt2D& a)   { *this=a; }
    ~_pnt2D()   {}
    _pnt2D* operator = (const _pnt2D *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //_pnt2D* operator = (const _pnt2D &a) { ...copy... return this; }
    };
struct _ang
    {
    double  ang;    // center angle of section
    double  dis;    // max distance of ang section
    double pdis;    // max perpendicular distance of +/-90deg section
    // inline
    _ang()  {}
    _ang(_ang& a)   { *this=a; }
    ~_ang() {}
    _ang* operator = (const _ang *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //_ang* operator = (const _ang &a) { ...copy... return this; }
    };
const int    angs=400;  // must be divisible by 4
const int    angs4=angs>>2;
const double dang=2.0*M_PI/double(angs);
const double dang2=0.5*dang;
_ang ang[angs];
List<_pnt2D> pnt;
_pnt2D bbox[2],obb[4],center;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void compute_OBB()
    {
    _pnt2D ppp[4];
    int i,j; double a,b,dx,dy;
    _ang *aa,*bb;
    _pnt2D p,*pp; DWORD *q;
    // convert bmp -> pnt[]
    pnt.num=0;
    Graphics::TBitmap *bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp->LoadFromFile("in.bmp");
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
    for (p.y=0;p.y<bmp->Height;p.y++)
     for (q=(DWORD*)bmp->ScanLine[int(p.y)],p.x=0;p.x<bmp->Width;p.x++)
      if ((q[int(p.x)]&255)<20)
       pnt.add(p);
    delete bmp;
    // axis aligned bbox
    bbox[0]=pnt[0];
    bbox[1]=pnt[0];
    for (pp=pnt.dat,i=0;i<pnt.num;i++,pp++)
        {
        if (bbox[0].x>pp->x) bbox[0].x=pp->x;
        if (bbox[0].y>pp->y) bbox[0].y=pp->y;
        if (bbox[1].x<pp->x) bbox[1].x=pp->x;
        if (bbox[1].y<pp->y) bbox[1].y=pp->y;
        }
    center.x=(bbox[0].x+bbox[1].x)*0.5;
    center.y=(bbox[0].y+bbox[1].y)*0.5;
    // ang[] table init
    for (aa=ang,a=0.0,i=0;i<angs;i++,aa++,a+=dang)
        {
        aa->ang=a;
        aa-> dis=0.0;
        aa->pdis=0.0;
        }
    // ang[].dis
    for (pp=pnt.dat,i=0;i<pnt.num;i++,pp++)
        {
        dx=pp->x-center.x;
        dy=pp->y-center.y;
        a=atan2(dy,dx);
        j=floor((a/dang)+0.5); if (j<0) j+=angs; j%=angs;
        a=(dx*dx)+(dy*dy);
        if (ang[j].dis<a) ang[j].dis=a;
        }
    for (aa=ang,i=0;i<angs;i++,aa++) aa->dis=sqrt(aa->dis);
    // ang[].adis
    for (aa=ang,i=0;i<angs;i++,aa++)
     for (bb=ang,j=0;j<angs;j++,bb++)
        {
        a=fabs(aa->ang-bb->ang);
        if (a>M_PI) a=(2.0*M_PI)-a;
        if (a<=0.5*M_PI)
            {
            a=bb->dis*cos(a);
            if (aa->pdis<a) aa->pdis=a;
            }
        }
    // find best oriented bbox (the best angle is ang[j].ang)
    for (b=0,j=0,i=0;i<angs;i++)
        {
        dx =ang[i].pdis; i+=angs4; i%=angs;
        dy =ang[i].pdis; i+=angs4; i%=angs;
        dx+=ang[i].pdis; i+=angs4; i%=angs;
        dy+=ang[i].pdis; i+=angs4; i%=angs;
        a=dx*dy; if ((b>a)||(i==0)) { b=a; j=i; }
        }
    // compute endpoints for OBB
    i=j;
    ppp[0].x=ang[i].pdis*cos(ang[i].ang);
    ppp[0].y=ang[i].pdis*sin(ang[i].ang); i+=angs4; i%=angs;
    ppp[1].x=ang[i].pdis*cos(ang[i].ang);
    ppp[1].y=ang[i].pdis*sin(ang[i].ang); i+=angs4; i%=angs;
    ppp[2].x=ang[i].pdis*cos(ang[i].ang);
    ppp[2].y=ang[i].pdis*sin(ang[i].ang); i+=angs4; i%=angs;
    ppp[3].x=ang[i].pdis*cos(ang[i].ang);
    ppp[3].y=ang[i].pdis*sin(ang[i].ang); i+=angs4; i%=angs;
    obb[0].x=center.x+ppp[0].x+ppp[3].x;
    obb[0].y=center.y+ppp[0].y+ppp[3].y;
    obb[1].x=center.x+ppp[1].x+ppp[0].x;
    obb[1].y=center.y+ppp[1].y+ppp[0].y;
    obb[2].x=center.x+ppp[2].x+ppp[1].x;
    obb[2].y=center.y+ppp[2].y+ppp[1].y;
    obb[3].x=center.x+ppp[3].x+ppp[2].x;
    obb[3].y=center.y+ppp[3].y+ppp[2].y;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I used mine dynamic list template so:

`List<double> xxx;` is the same as `double xxx[];`

`xxx.add(5);` adds `5` to end of the list

`xxx[7]` access array element (safe)

`xxx.dat[7]` access array element (unsafe but fast direct access)

`xxx.num` is the actual used size of the array

`xxx.reset()` clears the array and set `xxx.num=0`

`xxx.allocate(100)` preallocate space for `100` items

You can ignore the `// convert bmp -> pnt[]` VCL part as you got your data already.

I recommend to also take a look at my:

- [3D OBB approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62284464/2521214)

Comment: Good, thank you for the detailed and sophisticated solution you had provided.

Comment: @My_Cat_Jessica I added link to related QA with 3D port of this