# largest circle inside convex polygon

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry

I'm working on a problem of inscribing largest circle in convex polygon. The algorithm should be O(nlogn) time complexity.
I know that it's been discussed on this forum, that the possible solution is using straight skeletons.
I found simple algorithm, which find radius of the largest circle in O(nlogn).
Link to page with algorithm http://e-maxx.ru/algo/inscribed_circle , with detailed description in Russian. Shortly, idea is in shrinking sides of polygon with erasing sides, that converts to point firstly. In the end of the process polygon should turn to point or line.
In the description it says that finding coordinates of the center of circle is trivial. However, I can't figure out how to modify algorithm to find radius with center of the circle.
Code in C++:

```
const double EPS = 1E-9;
const double PI = ...;
 
struct pt {
    double x, y;
    pt()  { }
    pt (double x, double y) : x(x), y(y)  { }
    pt operator- (const pt & p) const {
        return pt (x-p.x, y-p.y);
    }
};
 
double dist (const pt & a, const pt & b) {
    return sqrt ((a.x-b.x)*(a.x-b.x) + (a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y));
}
 
double get_ang (const pt & a, const pt & b) {
    double ang = abs (atan2 (a.y, a.x) - atan2 (b.y, b.x));
    return min (ang, 2*PI-ang);
}
 
struct line {
    double a, b, c;
    line (const pt & p, const pt & q) {
        a = p.y - q.y;
        b = q.x - p.x;
        c = - a * p.x - b * p.y;
        double z = sqrt (a*a + b*b);
        a/=z, b/=z, c/=z;
    }
};
 
double det (double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    return a * d - b * c;
}
 
pt intersect (const line & n, const line & m) {
    double zn = det (n.a, n.b, m.a, m.b);
    return pt (
        - det (n.c, n.b, m.c, m.b) / zn,
        - det (n.a, n.c, m.a, m.c) / zn
    );
}
 
bool parallel (const line & n, const line & m) {
    return abs (det (n.a, n.b, m.a, m.b)) < EPS;
}
 
double get_h (const pt & p1, const pt & p2,
    const pt & l1, const pt & l2, const pt & r1, const pt & r2)
{
    pt q1 = intersect (line (p1, p2), line (l1, l2));
    pt q2 = intersect (line (p1, p2), line (r1, r2));
    double l = dist (q1, q2);
    double alpha = get_ang (l2 - l1, p2 - p1) / 2;
    double beta = get_ang (r2 - r1, p1 - p2) / 2;
    return l * sin(alpha) * sin(beta) / sin(alpha+beta);
}
 
struct cmp {
    bool operator() (const pair<double,int> & a, const pair<double,int> & b) const {
        if (abs (a.first - b.first) > EPS)
            return a.first < b.first;
        return a.second < b.second;
    }
};
 
int main() {
    int n;
    vector<pt> p;
    ... чтение n и p ...
 
    vector<int> next (n), prev (n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        next[i] = (i + 1) % n;
        prev[i] = (i - 1 + n) % n;
    }
 
    set < pair<double,int>, cmp > q;
    vector<double> h (n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        h[i] = get_h (
            p[i], p[next[i]],
            p[i], p[prev[i]],
            p[next[i]], p[next[next[i]]]
        );
        q.insert (make_pair (h[i], i));
    }
 
    double last_time;
    while (q.size() > 2) {
        last_time = q.begin()->first;
        int i = q.begin()->second;
        q.erase (q.begin());
 
        next[prev[i]] = next[i];
        prev[next[i]] = prev[i];
        int nxt = next[i],   nxt1 = (nxt+1)%n,
            prv = prev[i],   prv1 = (prv+1)%n;
        if (parallel (line (p[nxt], p[nxt1]), line (p[prv], p[prv1])))
            break;
 
        q.erase (make_pair (h[nxt], nxt));
        q.erase (make_pair (h[prv], prv));
 
        h[nxt] = get_h (
            p[nxt], p[nxt1],
            p[prv1], p[prv],
            p[next[nxt]], p[(next[nxt]+1)%n]
        );
        h[prv] = get_h (
            p[prv], p[prv1],
            p[(prev[prv]+1)%n], p[prev[prv]],
            p[nxt], p[nxt1]
        );
 
        q.insert (make_pair (h[nxt], nxt));
        q.insert (make_pair (h[prv], prv));
    }
 
    cout << last_time << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you know the centre, just find the distance between it and each side. The shortest one is he radius.

Comment: You'll need to keep track of all vertices of a shrinking polygon. In the end of a shrinking process all vertices converge either to a point which is a center of the inscribed circle, or to a line, then you can pick up either of the ends of this line as a center of the circle. The modifications of the algorithm are not trivial, but not very hard either.

Comment: you run the algo again and stop on first side of shrinked polygon reaching the center then the radius is distance between center and original edge position... but I think faster would be just compute perpendicular distance between each edge and center and use the smallest one as radius. Also [shrinking polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22068534/2521214) correctly is not easy task... take a look at this for other inspiration [Inscribing two circles in convex polygon, with max sum of radiuses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67429729/2521214)