# Minimum area bounding rectangle contains minimum distance track of convex hull

Tags: algorithm, vector, geometry, linear-algebra, computational-geometry

I am working on some project and I have stuck at proving that minimum area bounding rectangle contains 2 edges ( have 2 edges identical) same as minimum distance track of convex hull ( that contains all points of convex hull). Minimum distance track of convex hull is found by: From all edges find the point of convex hull with the most distance of that point and store it in the vector dist. Then take the edge and point that have min value from dist. At the end make parallel line to selected edge trough the selected point.
Now I have to prove that minimum bounding rectangle contains 2 edges, that I got in min distance track. Any Idea how to do that is very welcome.

Minimum track in blue line:

[image: img]

Minimum bounding rectangle:

[image: img]

Comment: Please show what code you've already tried.

Comment: @Yserbius I did a bitonic binary search, so I found a a greatest distance for every edge. By for loop I have iterated trough all edges and found minimal distance from maximal distances (for every edge). So I found minimal width track. Now I only want to prove that, this track is in one of the minimum bounding boxes. By doing a lot of examples I saw this is case, but how to prove that? So to sum I need a prove  correctness of that lemma ž

Comment: see [2D OBB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42997918/2521214)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prove it, because it's not true.  Here's a counter-example:

[image]

The area of Triangle 1 is its base*height/2.  Let's consider the 3 possible bases: **A**, **B**, and **C**.

For each base, you can form a bounding box for Triangle 1 that includes that base.
In each case, the bounding box of Triangle 1 has area base*height, and Triangle 1 takes up exactly half of it, so *all of those bounding boxes are the same size*.

However, only in *one* case -- base **A**, does that bounding box include the entire figure, including Triangle 2.  Therefore any bounding box for the entire figure that includes line **C** must be bigger.  Similarly, any bounding box that includes **D** must be bigger.

However, the minimum width track that includes the entire figure obviously *does* include **C** or **D**, so the minimum width track does *not* share edges with the minimum bounding box.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If the rectangle that you determine is the same as that obtained by rotating calipers (which I believe is true), then that rectangle contains a side and three other vertices.

Then it should be possible to show that if a rectangle contains four vertices but no side, you can rotate it slightly so that the area decreases (in other terms, the derivative of the area on the angle is nonzero).

Comment: @MattTimmermans: don't take me wrong, all sides of the rectangle adjust as a function of the angle (otherwise the rectangle area would be constant).

Comment: Thanks, this is actually answer on one other question I was wondering is it true and how to prove it

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more how to show that if a rectangle contains four vertices but no side, you can rotate it slightly so that the area decreases

Comment: @ProjekatPr: work out the equations.

Comment: tkank you a lot